# Solutions for a a nonlinear system expressed in state space form

Tags: systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

If for a linear system in state-space representation given by
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x(t)
=A(t)x(t)+B(t)u(t)\\
y(t)
=C(t)x(t)+D(t)u(t)
\end{cases}$$
the state and output solutions are given by
$$\begin{cases}
x(t)=e^{A(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^{t}e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau\\
y(t)=Ce^{A(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+C\int_{t_0}^{t}e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau+Du(t),
\end{cases}$$
In case of a nonlinear system given in state space representation as
$$\begin{cases}\dot x=f(t,x,u)\\
y=g(t,x,u)\end{cases}$$
there is a general procedure to find out the corresponding solutions? Or I have always to apply a linearization to boil down to a linear representation? Or alternatively we have to proceede with numerical methods?

Comment: Are you sure you typed the expressions correctly?  In the first equation $B$ seems a constant, while in the second $B$ is a function of $t$. Also, the second equation is not a differential equation. If that's the case, in the 4th equation replace $C$ with $B$ and then $D$ with $C$

Comment: Yes, they were all typos. Thanks!

Comment: there are still typos : for your solutions to be correct, $A,B,C,D$ need to be constant in the first place, hence you shouldn't write them as $A(t),B(t)$...etc
also, to briefly answer your question : there is no general procedure / solution in the non-linear case

Comment: @gdcvdqpl ah ok...in case the matrices depend on $t$ how can I obtain the solution?

Comment: well, there is also no general solution in that case... except if you accept infinite series or a weird kind of integral called "multiplicative integral" or "product integral", but this is pretty uncommon to see them used in control theory anyway.
If you still want some reference on this matter, I would suggest :
"Product integration, its history and applications" by Antonín Slavík
and "Product Integration with Application to Differential Equations" by John Day Dollard and Charles N. Friedman

Comment: hooo and suddenly I get why you are confused about the constant matrices $A, B$... in the expression $e^{A(t-t_0)}$ and $e^{A(t-\tau)}$, $t-t_0$ and $t-\tau$ are coefficients ! you might as well write $e^{(t-t_0)A}$ and $e^{(t-\tau)A}$ for disambiguation

Comment: Ah okkk thanks very much!!

Comment: @gdcvdqpl The  last question: if for linear system usually the discretization is realized from the solution of the ss equation, in nonlinear case again there are no general procedure but usually numerical methods are used? I have not found out anything about disretization of nonlinear system

Comment: indeed, the most usual ones are the Runge-Kutta methods

Comment: Ok thank you so much again!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128860/discussion-between-pawel-and-gdcvdqpl).